# Thermoacoustic mechanism for a thermoacoustic engine

Tags: thermodynamics, acoustics, heat-engine

How exactly does a thermoacoustic engine work? (I don't mean the engineering part) I understand the part on the Brayton cycle occurring and all, but how might we measure the numerical efficiency for an actual physical thermoacoustic engine, and how can obtain the maximum upper efficiency (why is not carnot efficiency)? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If my cursory research and my understanding of your question are correct, the efficiency of these engines is a function of how much of the acoustic power generated by the engine is utilized in the cooler, in other words how much work the acoustic power can be made to do.

Maximum efficiency is achieved by optimizing three parameters:

- the radius of the flow channels in the engine
- the radius of the flow channels in the cooler
- the relative position of the cooler